# CPU fan extremely fast even with 0% CPU

Tags: linux, debian, crunchbang, cpu-frequency

I just reinstalled my operating system (Crunchbang on Debian testing), and all of a sudden the fan is running as fast as it can even with 0% CPU. The air coming out of it is cold. The only CPU frequency governors available according to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors` are performance and powersave, and it was already set to powersave by default. What else could be wrong?

```
ruukasu@cb-lt:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +39.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +39.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +32.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +39.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is temperature.

Comment: @illuminÉ How would one change this "targeted temperature"? I don't have `sensors` and it's not in the debian repos (unless it's under a different name). I don't think it's processing related because my CPU always stays around 1%, sometimes it actually manages 0%.

Comment: The package is called `lm-sensors` and is in the Debian repos.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol`, they can take care of setting the right RPM for your fans. Alter installation run `sensors-detect` (as root). It should give you a name of a kernel module at the end of the putput:

```
To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
it87
#----cut here----
```

You have to add your module to `/etc/modules`, this won't work without it. If you just add this, you have to reboot your PC. But you can load the module manually using `modprobe`.

Next run `sensors` and check the `temp*` and `fan*` lines for setting appropriate values in the `fancontrol` config. In my case it looks like this:

```
$ sensors
it8718-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +1.22 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:          +1.79 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
+5V:          +2.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in5:          +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in6:          +1.25 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in7:          +2.99 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:         +4.08 V
fan1:         579 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        -55.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +28.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +60.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:         -1.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +1.263 V
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

`temp2` and `fan1` describe my processor. So, if you have problems with a fan because it rotates to fast, you have to make a config file using `pwmconfig`. You can also write the config manually, it should look like this:

```
# cat /etc/fancontrol
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/it87.656
DEVNAME=hwmon0=it8718
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/temp2_input
FCFANS= hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=45
MINSTART=hwmon0/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=0
MAXPWM=hwmon0/device/pwm1=255
```

You just have to pay attention to the values and change them according to `lm-sensors` output. I think all lines are self-explanatory.

Comment: I ran `lm-sensors` and hit enter at every question. In the first question, it found one thing (`Intel digital thermal sensor... Success!`). I then ran `sudo pwmconfig`, and it said `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`. If pwmconfig won't run, will fancontrol be any use?

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of `sensors`

Comment: I added `coretemp` to `/etc/modules`, but I ran `lsmod` and it was already loaded. It looks like `pwmconfig` won't work. Can I remove the `FCFANS=` line in /etc/fancontrol and have it still work? I have a tempX device (temp1) but not a fanX device.

Comment: Without the fan device it won't work because the system doesn't know which fan should be set.

Comment: Check this thread -- http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=84455